# QGIS does not react when using large expression in the Expression Dialog

Tags: qgis, expression

QGIS does not respond when pasting a large expression in QGIS with If-statements following each other:

```
If("A", 'B',
  If("C", 'D',
    If("E", 'F',
      etc)))
```

I have checked my statement, it is correct and it works in QGIS 3.4 or lower. I have done some testing, and it seems that with each extra bracket the system takes longer to process or evaluate the expression. After about 10 repeating If-statements the waiting time becomes multiple minutes.

Comment: The complexer the expression gets, the more features and attributes your layer contains etc., the longer it takes to calculate, that's quite normal. Without having more details about all this plus your exact expression, it's difficult to help. But have a look at `case when` expression.

Comment: I'm not talking about the calculation which takes long, it is in my case the paste itself into the expression dialog which takes forever in qgis >3.10. 
That didn't occur in QGIS 3.4 or lower.

I will try the case when expression :)

Comment: If you provide your expression, I can try it here. However, I guess that it could have to do that QGIS already starts calculation when you insert the expression, e.g. to return the preview under the expression field: so a complex expression can block the editor, before you run it.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of nesting `if` statements, use case to avoid augmenting complexity.

```
CASE
  WHEN "mycol" = 'A' THEN 'B'
  WHEN "mycol" = 'C' THEN 'D'
  WHEN "mycol" = 'E' THEN 'F'
  ELSE 'G'
END
```

If you are using database as a source, you may change the source to make your expression in the `SELECT` statement instead of QGIS expression level